# How to reference userform click events in VBA

Tags: vba, onclick, userform

I have a userform called 'dataBox' which is shown when the user clicks a command button. The user then inputs data and presses an OK command button on the userform to submit the data.

What I am struggling with and what i need to happen is this: If the user clicks the OK button on the userform, a sub called category2 runs. If the user clicks 'X' nothing happens.

here is my command button code

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

dataBox.Show
If dataBox.Controls(okCommandButton_Click) Then
category2 Range("A1")
End If

End Sub
```

The line

```
If dataBox.Controls(okCommandButton_Click) Then
```

is completely wrong and is the latest attempt at referencing when the ok click event fires but hopefully it is clear what I am trying to do. i have scoured the web for the answer and can't get it to work! Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just use an `inputbox()`?

Comment: Hi can you expand on that a bit please? Im new to this and self taught so there are gaping holes in my knowledge. Do you mean a MsgBox within the commandbutton_click?

Comment: I have posted an answer, hopefully providing you with a valid alternative on your userform.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** There are a few things you should change in your code. First off, you better open your form by using a `DoCmd` like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "dataBox", acNormal
```

Secondly, instead of checking if the button is pressed in the commandbutton1's event, use the actual event itself.

```
Private Sub okCommandButton_Click()
    'Do something/add the data to somewhere
End Sub
```

If the 'X' button is clicked, the only thing that should happen is the closure of the databox form, so:

```
Private Sub XButton_Click()
    DoCmd.Close acForm, "dataBox", acSavePrompt
End Sub
```

---

**Info on inputbox:** I assume you are familiar with a messagebox, or `msgbox()`. The `InputBox()` command is essentially the same, but allows you to enter data and do something with it.
The setup of your 'databox' form is alike an inputbox.

[image]

The inputbox above is called this way:

```
Dim answer as string
answer = Inputbox("I am an inputbox.", "enter data", "enter data here")
```

The following situations can occur:

```
If you press cancel:
answer = ""

If you press 'X':
answer = ""

If you press OK:
answer = "Value entered in the text line"
```

The following article on msdn will probably offer more insight;
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6z0ak68w(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Ok thanks for expanding. Problem is, I need two fields for data and it appears that you can only have one? Therefore I'd need two boxes and I'd rather just have the one collecting both pieces of data.

Comment: 'Secondly, instead of checking if the button is pressed in the commandbutton1's event, use the actual event itself'. I tried this but 'category2 Range("A1")' isn't recognised by the userform's ok button click event. Is this because category2 has been coded as a Private Sub? Will it work if it is 'Public Sub'? Becuase this would definately be an easier solution.